# Asymptotic expansion of integral

Tags: calculus

Find the first two terms in asymptotic expansion (as $x \rightarrow \infty$) of the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x \sin^{2} t}dt.$$

Comment: Please fix your math symbols. Also, Taylor's theorem is probably what you need.

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might help you making your post easier to read.

Comment: This is the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Answer (score 2):

$\sin^2t$ is an even function, so consider the integral:

$$\int ^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}e^{-x\sin ^2 t}dt$$

For very large values of x, non zero values of $\sin t$ will make the integrand very small. So we are justified in making this approximation:

$$\int ^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}e^{-x\, t^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\frac{\pi  \sqrt{x}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Since the error function is asymptotic to 1, we can further simplify it as

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{x}}$$

Or we could notice that only very small values of $ t$ makes any contribution so we can use the gaussian integral formula (for $(\infty,-\infty)$) to get the same answer. You want half of this result.

Edit: As M.Wing has suggested:

> I like your answer. May I suggest to write the exponential term as $\exp(−xt^2)$ times $\exp(−x(\sin^2(t)−t^2))$. The first term is then used as a Gaussian (as in your calculation); the second term can be expanded in Taylor series of t around zero.

Doing this gives the following integral

$$x\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-xt^2} \left(\sin ^2t-t^2\right) \, dt=x\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{-1/x} \left(e^{1/x} (x-1)-x\right)}{2 x^{3/2}}$$

(Remember the integrand is practically zero beyond $\pi/2$)

The first term is a very good approximation, it is within %5 for $x>5$ but the second term makes it even better. The ratios to the actual result:

[image]

Comment: I like your answer. May I suggest to write the exponential term as $exp(-xt^2)$ times $exp(-x(sin^2(t)-t^2))$. The first term is then used as a Gaussian (as in your calculation); the second term can be expanded in Taylor series of $t$ around zero.

Comment: @M.Wind I found the next term as you suggested. It actualyl improved the approximation quite a bit.

Comment: Your method is valid, but your result seems to be incorrect. I obtained the following result: $f(x) = 0.5 \sqrt \frac { \pi}{x}  (1 + 1/(4x))$.

Comment: what did you evaluate to get the second term?

Comment: @M.Wind https://i.imgur.com/5bQu6NC.png My 2 term approximation is orange, yours green and my 3 term approximation is red. The methods appear to be correct but your's is better.

Comment: @M.Wind Oh, you integrated $$x \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{3} t^4 e^{t^2 (-x)} \, dt$$ using the taylor approximation of $$\sin ^2(t)-t^2$$ which ended up giving a closer approximation.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 2):

As Lucian pointed out in a comment $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-x \sin^{2} t}dt=\frac{ \pi}{2}  e^{-x/2}\, I_0\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ At this point, one could use the asymptotic expansion given by Hankel for the modified Bessel function of the first kind $$I_{\alpha}(z)=\frac{e^z}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\Big(1-\frac {4\alpha^2-1}{8z}+\frac {(4\alpha^2-1)(4\alpha^2-9)}{2! (8z)^2}-\frac {(4\alpha^2-1)(4\alpha^2-9)(4\alpha^2-25)}{3! (8z)^3}+\cdots\Big)$$ Applied to $\alpha=0$ and $z=\frac x2$, this gives $$f(x)\approx\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2
   \sqrt{x}}\left(1+\frac{1}{4 x}+\frac{9}{32 x^2}+\frac{75}{128 x^3}+\cdots\right)$$